# Nested SVG elements with Raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Trying to implement nested SVG elements with [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com).

I think this Question is related to

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/raphaeljs/tzdj3y2DDwg

Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Are you tied to Raphael ? If you move to Snap (same author, so very similar), you can nest easier with groups, depends if you need compatibility with older browsers. Not sure of another way, other than using sets as the groups answer states.

Comment: Thanks lan. Not really. Actually, I found Raphael after reading Snap release articles, and I just thought Raphael is a good to start and less information for Snap. Perhaps, I need to go Snap, if it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've maneged to partially implement nested svg approach.

This is a short example:

```
var outer_svg = Raphael(document.getElementById('container'), paper_width, paper_height);
outer_svg.canvas.setAttribute('id', 'outer_svg');
var inner_svg = Raphael(document.getElementById("outer_svg"), paper_width, paper_height/2);
inner_svg.canvas.setAttribute('y', paper_height/2);
```

Here we created inner_svg that is half the height of outer_svg and is positioned at the bottom of outer_svg.

The canvas object represent the svg dom element. So if we give it an id attr then we can adress it to be the parent of another svg. And we can set the x,y coords relative to parent svg element.

Now the sad part:seems that canvas doesn't support animation method, so we cannot animate the whole svg child element. Sets don't help here because drawing elements parts that are outside child svg canvas disappear (as they should).